# Vue cli env without prefix VUE_APP

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

is possible to use env in vue cli without de prefix VUE_APP,

Example in `.env` without prefix `VUE_APP`:

```
API_MESSAGE_URL = localhost:5000/v1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can name your ENV variables however you like but...

> Note that only NODE_ENV, BASE_URL, and variables that start with VUE_APP_ will be statically embedded into the client bundle with webpack.DefinePlugin. It is to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name

[Vue CLI docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables)